Use a DB backend function on the result of an aggreate in Django
Is it possible to have a DB function executed on the result of an aggregate?
In my case, I have this aggregate:
geom = SomeModel.objects.filter(otherModel=xxx).aggregate(geom=Union("geom"))

Let's say I would like to run another DB function on the output of the aggregate (like Reverse for instance. How can I achieve this?
